# Cannot resolve symbol 'OAuth2AuthenticationToken'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

**My Configure java file GoogleOAuth2SuccessHandler:**

```
package ru.connor.shopping_app.config;


import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.RedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import ru.connor.shopping_app.repository.RoleRepository;
import ru.connor.shopping_app.repository.UserRepository;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class GoogleOAuth2SuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;


    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        OAuth2AuthenticationToken token = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

    }

}
```

I added the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

But for some reason, the compiler gives the following error:
***Cannot resolve symbol 'OAuth2AuthenticationToken'***

I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: you did not import OAuth2AuthenticationToken in your class.

Comment: Yes, because the IntelliJ itself does not offer to import. I'd like to, but I can't .